# DB2 SMP Small vs Entry

Tags: php, db2, ibm-cloud

I have this code in my .php app in BlueMix:

```
$sql = "SELECT PROJECT_NAME FROM BLUE_FORMS.BDR_PC_PROJECTS WHERE USER_NAME='$user'";
if ($conn2) {   
   $stmt = db2_exec($conn2, $sql);
   echo "<select>";
   echo "<option disabled selected>";
   while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
      echo "<option value='".$row['PROJECT_NAME']."'>".$row['PROJECT_NAME']."</option>";
   }
   echo "</select>";
}
```

It works just fine under DB2 Entry but when I swithched over the SMP Small the code above generates an empty drop down box. I know the connection works because I can log into my page and user ids and password are stored in the db. If I echo the $sql on the page and I copy and paste the query into the db console it workd just fine. So what the heck. any ideas. The tables in both dbs are of course identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below and check:-

```
$sql = "SELECT PROJECT_NAME FROM BLUE_FORMS.BDR_PC_PROJECTS WHERE USER_NAME='$user'";
if ($conn2) {//check connection
    $stmt = db2_exec($conn2, $sql);
    if(!db2_stmt_error($stmt)){ //check for error
        echo "<select>";
        echo "<option disabled selected>";
        while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
            echo "<option value='".$row['PROJECT_NAME']."'>".$row['PROJECT_NAME']."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }else{
      echo "query_error".db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt); //print error
    }
}else{
    echo "connection error"; //print connection error if occur
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alive to Die !!! ok... I see what I did! I don't wnat to say what it was becasue I don't want to look stupid.